# How to avoid Laravel login redirect to latest AJAX call?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, redirect, authentication

There are multiple ajax requests happening on the page and if a user logs in, the user gets redirected to the latest url via the following snippet:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if(!session()->has('url.intended')) {
        session(['url.intended' => url()->previous()]);
    }
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

This url may be an ajax returning some json. How do I avoid the intended url being ajax? I obviously want it to redirect to the actual previous page instead of some random ajax call. Is the only way to avoid this by just saving the redirect url as a query param like `/login?redirect_uri=/go-here-after-login` ?

Also, if you have a totally different approach in mind, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, the intended URL is stored in the session when the user is blocked from viewing a page via the auth middleware. The page the user attempted to visit is stored and when you use `redirect()->intended()` the user is sent back to the page they tried to visit. The session should not be storing every visited URL (AJAX or otherwise) in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using `redirect()->intended()` for your purposes.

When an unauthenticated user tries to visit a page that is protected by the Auth middleware, they are redirected to your login page and only then is their intended URL (the URL they tried to visit) stored in the session.

When that user logs in, you can then redirect them to their intended page, or a fallback page of your choosing using `redirect()->intended()`. For example:

```
class LoginController
{
    public function handleLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(request()->only(['email', 'password']))) {
            return redirect()->intended('/your/fallback/url');

            // Or if you want to get a URL by its route name:
            // return redirect()->intended(route('route.name'));
        }

        // Handle what happens if the user's credentials were incorrect
    }
}
```

As far as I am aware, every URL the user visits (via AJAX or otherwise) *should not* be stored in the session and it's only when the Auth middleware kicks in that the intended URL is set.

In your code you're using `url()->previous()`, which redirects the user to their *referrer* (The page that originated the request i.e. the previous page) rather than the intended URL stored in the session.